# How would a excel formula be to check the range of cells if there is a value within a range and output the value of the row

Tags: excel

output that value in this row

example:

```
    A    B    C    D    E
1  one  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A
2  N/A  two  N/A  N/A  N/A
3  N/A  N/A  N/A   3   N/A
4  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A   4
```

Now lets say that in the F column I want to have all the values that only have a value different than N/A

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F
1  one  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A  one 
2  N/A  two  N/A  N/A  N/A  two
3  N/A  N/A  N/A   3   N/A   3
4  N/A  N/A  N/A  N/A   4    4
```

what I was thinking of doing was something like this
don't know how to use the vlookup for this...
don't know if this is the right course of action

```
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!$A:$A,1,false)),"N/A",""& value_here &"")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this in F1 and copy down

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(A1:E1<>"N/A"),A1:E1)
```

[image]

Edit: Use the Evaluate Formula tool to step through the formula and see how it works. First, the `(A1:E1<>"N/A")` is resolved into an array of False and one True values. Then that array is used as the divisor, which results in an array with many #Div/0! values for each False and numbers for each True.

Lookup is then performed, searching for a 2, which will find the position of the last number in the array, since all values are smaller than 1. The respective value of that array position is then returned.

Comment: What is the 2 an 1 for?

Comment: I added some explanation.